# react-native-gifted-chat tick not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

In my react-native-gifted-chat tick is not showing. New to react so not sure on how to fix this.

1. the message contains sent: true and recieve:true
2. using react-native > .61 and react-native-gifted-chat = 0.16.1
3. renderTicks is not boolean but a function. it just has currentMessage as paramters not even any props.

Do I have to write the ticks manually?

Comment: Please provide some code for your gifted chat setup

Comment: @jay Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is custom the renderTick, and render it directly in message.

```
// custom tick
const renderTick = (props) => {
  return (
    <Text>
      {props.currentMessage.isSent && "✓"}
      {props.currentMessage.isReceived && "✓"}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

And render the message like this:

```
// Custom message text
const renderMessageText = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>
      {props.currentMessage.text}
    </Text>
    renderTick(props)
  </View>
)
```